# ggplot2: how to graph only part of a time series

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to use `ggplot` to graph portions of time series data. For example, say I only wanted to graph the last five dates of this data. Is there away to specify this in `ggplot` without subsetting the data ahead of time? I tried using `xlim`, but it didn't work.

```
date <- c("2016-03-24","2016-03-25","2016-03-26","2016-03-27","2016-03-28",
              "2016-03-29","2016-03-30","2016-03-31","2016-04-01","2016-04-02")
Temp <- c(35,34,92,42,21,47,37,42,63,12)
df <- data.frame(date,Temp)
```

My attempt:

```
ggplot(df) + geom_line(aes(x=date,y=Temp)) + xlim("2016-03-29","2016-04-02")
```

My dates are formatted as `POSIXct`.

Comment: You may want to look the [`coord_cartesian`](http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/coord_cartesian.html) documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to enter the `xlim` values as `as.Date` or `as.POSIXct()`. Is this what you want?

```
df$date <- as.Date(df$date, format= "%Y-%m-%d", tz = "UTC")
ggplot(df) + geom_line(aes(x=date,y=Temp)) + 
xlim(as.Date(c("2016-03-30", "2016-04-02"), tz = "UTC", format = "%Y-%m-%d") )
```

[image]

PS: Be aware that you will get the following warning:

```
Warning message:
Removed 5 rows containing missing values (geom_path)
```